# Joining row from one table with the sum value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the table **IPAddressHistory** that contains three columns **IPAddressID**, **DateFrom** and **DateTo**, and another table **IPAddressTimeValue** with detailed values by particular time. So, I need select SUM values from **IPAddressTimeValue** related by **IPAddressID** between **DateFrom** and **DateTo** from **IPAddressHistory**. You can see what I want from [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7b5e/13), there I used, for example, the simple static dates from **IPAddressHistory** and UNION ALL. Thanks.

**Initial tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE IPAddressHistory(
  [IPAddressHistoryID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [IPAddressID] int NOT NULL,
  [DateFrom] datetime,
  [DateTo] datetime,
CONSTRAINT [PK_IPAddressHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IPAddressHistoryID] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE TABLE IPAddressTimeValue(
  [IPAddressTimeValueID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [IPAddressID] int NOT NULL,
  [Time] datetime,
  [CCNI] int,
  [TRNI] int,
CONSTRAINT [PK_IPAddressTimeValue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IPAddressTimeValueID] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

**Initial data:**

[image]
[image]

**Result output:**
[image]

Comment: Provide your desired output.

Comment: I need join two columns CCNI and TRNI from select from IPAddressHistory that are the SUM values from IPAddressTimeValue where Time between DateFrom and DateTo from IPAddressHistory select. Each row must contains IPAddressID, SUM(CCNI), SUM(TRNI), DateFrom and DateTo. Result output you can see after "Run SQL" on sqlfiddle page that I provided.

Comment: The data you provided on fiddle does not match your inserted values. Take a look at the dates from `20151220 to 20151221` for the ipaddressuid you have 70 and 35 as sum, not 40 and 20 as you data sample show. Please, let me know if I'm wrong or you are!

Comment: I'm wrong. saw that the dates are not inclusive.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in the question*.  Questions on Stack Overflow should not depend on external sites for the basic explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you need is this one:

```
select a.[IPAddressID], 
       a.[DateFrom], 
       a.[DateTo], 
       SUM([CCNI]) [CCNI], 
       SUM([TRNI]) [TRNI]
  from IPAddressHistory a
         INNER JOIN IPAddressTimeValue b 
                ON (a.[IPAddressID] = b.[IPAddressID])
 where b.[Time] > a.[DateFrom]
   and b.[Time] <= a.[DateTo]
 group by a.[IPAddressID], a.[DateFrom], a.[DateTo];
```

See it working here WITH you own select unions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/abfe6/5

To format the dates (datefrom and dateto) as you want, just use some date format function. Don't forget to use it on the select field also on the group by.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood correctly but you need something like this? Join tables via `IPAddressID` and use `DateFrom`, `DateTo` from `History` table in `WHERE` clause?

**UPDATED**

```
select h.IPAddressID, sum(CCNI) as CCNI, sum(TRNI) as TRNI, DateFrom, DateTo 
from IPAddressHistory h
left join IPAddressTimeValue v on h.IPAddressID = v.IPAddressID 
where v.[time] > h.DateFrom and v.[time] <= h.DateTo
group by h.IPAddressID, DateFrom, DateTo
```

You can test It at: <kbd>[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7629/8)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, DateFrom and DateTo must be taken from IPAddressHistory.

Comment: Your result is wrong since `between` is INCLUSIVE for both ends. So you are considering values that shouldn't be considered.